# what does a tf placeholder functions do

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing

I am trying to figure out what this piece of code does but I cannot figure out how it passed a image and what it does to the image.

The major line of code is this one

```
images1, images2 = preprocess(images, is_train, BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
```

pretty simple it is a function that get images it would think.

now the parameter images is this:

```
    images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3], name='images')
    is_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_train')
```

and this is the function for preprocess:

```
def preprocess(images, is_train, BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH):
def train():
    split = tf.split(images, [1, 1])
    shape = [1 for _ in range(split[0].get_shape()[1])]
    for i in range(len(split)):
        split[i] = tf.reshape(split[i], [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])
        split[i] = tf.image.resize_images(split[i], [IMAGE_HEIGHT + 8, IMAGE_WIDTH + 3])
        split[i] = tf.split(split[i], shape)
        for j in range(len(split[i])):
            split[i][j] = tf.reshape(split[i][j], [IMAGE_HEIGHT + 8, IMAGE_WIDTH + 3, 3])
            split[i][j] = tf.random_crop(split[i][j], [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])
            split[i][j] = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(split[i][j])
            split[i][j] = tf.image.random_brightness(split[i][j], max_delta=32. / 255.)
            split[i][j] = tf.image.random_saturation(split[i][j], lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
            split[i][j] = tf.image.random_hue(split[i][j], max_delta=0.2)
            split[i][j] = tf.image.random_contrast(split[i][j], lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
            split[i][j] = tf.image.per_image_standardization(split[i][j])
    return [tf.reshape(tf.concat(split[0], axis=0), [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3]),
        tf.reshape(tf.concat(split[1], axis=0), [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])]
def val():
    split = tf.split(images, [1, 1])
    shape = [1 for _ in range(split[0].get_shape()[1])]
    for i in range(len(split)):
        split[i] = tf.reshape(split[i], [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])
        split[i] = tf.image.resize_images(split[i], [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH])
        split[i] = tf.split(split[i], shape)
        for j in range(len(split[i])):
            split[i][j] = tf.reshape(split[i][j], [IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])
            split[i][j] = tf.image.per_image_standardization(split[i][j])
    return [tf.reshape(tf.concat(split[0], axis=0), [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3]),
        tf.reshape(tf.concat(split[1], axis=0), [BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 3])]
return tf.cond(is_train, train, val)
```

This is the whole code by the images

```
 if MODE == 'train':
    tarin_num_id = get_num_id(DATA_DIR, 'train')
elif MODE == 'eval':
    val_num_id = get_num_id(DATA_DIR, 'val')
images1, images2 = preprocess(images, is_train, BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH)
```

I dont know how this will process images and send it to the network.

Thank you for any help with this.

The whole code I am working on comes from here
https://github.com/digitalbrain79/person-reid

Comment: Check this out please for clarification https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder

Comment: I think I got it, so the actual information that is being submitted is done through a feed dict like this
feed_dict = {images: test_images, is_train: False}

Comment: So images: will then be defined as test images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is that the feed_dict is what is being passed and should contain the images that is needed.
     `feed_dict = {images: test_images, is_train: False}`
you load the images through a array like test_images and then pass this to the feed_dict. This saves time as you can load different images into the feed_dict and not change much of the code for train, validation, or testing
thank you @Chetan Vashisth for pointing to the feed_dict dictionary